# Cross-Origin Rejection Rejected: Same Origin policy prohibits the reading of remote resources (Reason: CORS request was not successful)

Tags: json, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf, cross-origin-read-blocking

good night Sir,

i want to show google map from getJson Url, and i already have method to parse data in database to jsonArray on the same project (other controller), when i call the url in map, i got this error

```
Cross-Origin Rejection Rejected: Same Origin policy prohibits the reading of remote resources at http://127.0.0.1:8080/edclistapps/map_list. (Reason: CORS request was not successful)
```

and i have js with getJSON method to call (json) from another service in my project to show marker in google map, and that service can be work, but my js and my getJson have console error, this is my js

```
 <div class="controls">
    <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
      <option value="">Merchant Grub</option>
   <option value="BAKMI GM">BAKMI GM</option>
  <option value="CHATIME">CHATIME</option>
  <option value="PUYO">PUYO</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script>

  var gmarkers1 = [];
  var markers1 = [];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ''
  });


  // init map
  function initialize() {
      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.121435, 106.774124);
    var styles = [{ "stylers": [{ "saturation": -80 }, { "gamma": 2 }] }, { "featureType": "water", "stylers": [{ "lightness": -15 }] }];

        var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: "EDC" });

      var mapOptions = { scrollwheel: false, zoom: 4, center: center, mapTypeControlOptions: { mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'] } };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

      var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/edclistapps/map_list";
      $.getJSON(url, function (markers1) {
          $.each(markers1, function(key,val){
              addMarker(key)
          });
      });

  }


  // add markers to map
  function addMarker(marker) {
      var category = marker[4];
      var title = marker[3];
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[8], marker[9]);
      var content = marker[3];
      var city = marker[6];
var myIcon='http://ruralshores.com/assets/marker-icon.png';
      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: title,
          position: pos,
          category: category,
          map: map,
        icon: myIcon
      });

      gmarkers1.push(marker1);

      // marker click listener
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
          return function () {
              console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
              infowindow.setContent(content);
          //  infowindow.setContent(city);
              infowindow.open(map, marker1);
              // map.panTo(this.getPosition()); // pan to lat/long of map marker
              map.setZoom(12);
          }
      })(marker1, content));
  }

  // filter markers by category
  filterMarkers = function (category) {
      for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
          marker = gmarkers1[i];
          // If is same category or category not picked
          if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
              marker.setVisible(true);

          }
          // categories don't match 
          else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
      }
  }

  // Init map
  initialize();

  </script>
```

i'm using springboot and thymeleaf, what must i do to make my code work?

Comment: You have to enable cross-origin requests for your domain, see [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

Comment: can you give me simply example what must i do? thank for you answer

Comment: See the link that I posted